# How to use multiple parameters in a handlebar helper with meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-helper

I am trying to create a custom helper using Meteor.  Following to the doc here:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars

I have tried to define my helper as follows:

```
Template.myTemplate.testHelper = function(foo, bar, options) {
    console.log(foo);
    console.log(bar);
}
```

My template looks like:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    {{#testHelper "value1" "value2"}}
    {{/testHelper}}
</template>
```

Looking at my console output, I expected to see 2 lines of output:

```
value1
value2
```

However my console looks like:

```
value1
function (data) {
    // don't create spurious annotations when data is same
    // as before (or when transitioning between e.g. `window` and
    // `undefined`)
    if ((data || Handlebars._defaultThis) ===
        (old_data || Handlebars._defaultThis))
      return fn(data);
    else
      return Spark.setDataContext(data, fn(data));
  }
```

Note, I am completely new to meteor, and to handlebars.  I think I would be much happier using underscore, but the documentation for meteor glances over underscore almost entirely.  Am I doing something wrong defining my helper function?  It seems that it is not seeing the second parameter "bar", and instead interpreting that as the options.  (Note: if I console.log(options) it returns 'undefined').

Meteor version 0.4.0 (8f4045c1b9)

Answer (score 67):

Your logic is good, just make some changes to the template

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{testHelper "value1" "value2"}}
</template>
```

Bare in mind that the testHelper function is only defined in the myTemplate template.

If you want to register testHelper globally  you'll need to do something like this

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('testHelper', function(foo, bar){
  console.log(foo);
  console.log(bar);
});
```

Have fun

Comment: This is not valid if you need a {{#if}} Content {{/if}} style helper.

Comment: one can combine the helpers in such scenario: `{{#if testHelper "v1" "v2"}} some Template {{/if}}`

Comment: Where is the `Handlebars.registerHelper` supposed to be put?

Comment: @KarlMorrison – you can put it really anywhere where client code is run I for example commonly put it in `myApp/client/lib/helpers/template-helpers.js`  Also, with newer versions of Meteor you'd want to register each individual helper separately using this syntax: `Template.registerHelper('myHelperName', function(arg1, arg2) { [...] });`. You don't need to wrap this code in anything, just drop it in your template-helper.js as individual code snippets with plenty of whitespace between each of these snippets for readability. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Addition to

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{testHelper "value1" "value2"}}
</template>
```

Instead of passing a value as a parameter pass the function as parameter Here is the code for that

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{ testHelper1 (testHelper2 "value2") }}
</template>
```

Comment: That helped me a lot, the ( ) around the second helper was what I was searching for. Really hard to google :)