# Meteor - How to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to Helper without using key-value pairs?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

In Meteor, we can pass values to a helper like so:

```
{{testHelper abc="123" xyz="987"}}
```

and the helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('testHelper', function(opt) {
    console.log(opt.hash.abc);
    console.log(opt.hash.xyz);
});
```

---

Is there a way to do just:

```
{{testHelper "123" "987"}}
```

and get the values back as an index instead? Like so:

```
Template.registerHelper('testHelper', function(opt) {
    console.log(opt.hash[0]);
    console.log(opt.hash[1]);
});
```

I know you can define a function which takes two arguments, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12567466/2317532), and it'd work. But I'd ideally want the function to take any number of arguments.

If I `console.log(opt);` here, I'd get `123`, whereas I want `opt.hash[0]` (or, even better, `opt[0]`) to be `123`, and `opt.hash[1]` to be `987`.

The reason I want this is

1. `"123"` looks cleaner than `abc="123"` when the key value doesn't matter,
2. but still allow the helper to accept any number of
   parameters.

I have tried passing an array as a parameter `{{testHelper ["123", "987"]}}`, but that produced a syntax error.

Comment: Your question answered a doubt I had xD

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of an older question, but I just tested and something like this works:

```
// JS
Template.registerHelper('concat', function () {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1).join('');
});

// Template
{{ concat "a" "b" "c" }}
```

Basically, the normal JavaScript `arguments` value is still available in a helper.

The last argument is always the Spacebars object (the one with the hash), but if you slice that off like I did (`Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1)`), you basically get all of the other arguments in an array, which you can then use as you like.

Answer (score 1):

So this might not be a perfect solution but you can pass in an array if a helper for it already exists, so assuming you have a way to inject the values into the helper array, for instance with Session, you can access it in your original method.

```
Session.set('tempArray', ['abc', 'xyz']);

Template.registerHelper('tempArray', function() {
  return Session.get('tempArray');
});

Template.registerHelper('readArray', function(arr) {
  console.log(arr[0]);
});

<!-- template -->
{{readArray tempArray}}

//outputs: 'abc'
```